# In Neural network prediction(not classification), What Cost function shall i use?

Tags: neural-network, octave, prediction, backpropagation

Would you please provide me with some cost function that i can use in Neural Network back propagation prediction.

I have a prediction to be done in backpropagation, but i dont know if i can use any cost function.

Are cost function dependent on the activation function that we use?

If i use sin(x) as activation function then what will be the cost function?

Answer (score -1):

1) In the course [Machine Learning on Cursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml), Andrew Ng provides this cost function: 
`J(theta) = -1/m*( y*log(h(X*theta)) + (1-y)*log(1-h(X*theta)) )`,

where `log` is a natural logarithm, `h(X*theta)` is output from NN. Apparently, this comes from [Kullback–Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback-Leibler_divergence) and [Cross-entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy).

2) The general idea is that your cost function is convex and classifier via optimization function finds one global minimum. If you use the above equation for classification such that your `y`s are 0 or 1, this function will be convex.
As a side note, the cost function `J(theta) = 1/2*( h(x) - y )^2` is not convex when you use NN for classification.

3) Yes, especially for gradient calculation whose form is different depending on an activation function.

4) First of all why would you invent the wheel if it's already invented?
It's tricky question but I can give some clues. Your Cost function has to

1. give ideally 0 when output is exactly as it supposed to be:

   - h(x)=1 given x and y is 1
   - h(x)=0 given x and y is 0
2. The cost function has to give you any huge number otherwise, e.g. h(x)=0 when y=1 etc.
3. The cost function has to be convex.

Taking into account this features, you would have to work out the Cost Function. Besides, it looks like if you used `sin(x)`, you would probably have to limit your argument `X*theta` to -pi ... pi.

Comment: I think that the first one is a cost function for classification problem (it assumes that y matrix consists of only zeros and ones).

Answer (score -1):

Actually, ZikO, you should check the coursera materials again.  The first cost function is still non-convex.  Perhaps you are confusing neural networks with logistic regression.  In the latter, using the entropic cost-function does indeed make the problem convex, whereas ordinary least squares does not.  In neural networks, both cost functions are non-convex.  According to Prof. Ng, however, this is not a big problem for neural networks.